# How to get two separate links in one Google Sheet cell

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to figure out how to display two separate words, each with its own unique hyperlink, into a single cell in Google Sheets. Example is in the image below.

[image]

Can someone please help me figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you type the words in the cell first, you can highlight one word or phrase you'd like to hyperlink and click the link button:

[image: Example word highlighted in cell, link button circled]

Enter the desired URL and click "Apply"
[image: Example of link UI]

Repeat as desired.

[image: Example of second phrase highlighted, link button circled]

[image: Example complete with two different hyperlinks]

You can also use the shortcut command+k (Mac) or ctrl+k (PC) to link the word/phrase after highlighting it.

Comment: thank you! Somehow I overlooked the obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to get two pretty links that look like `WikiPedia` or `Wiktionary` in the same cell, but you can insert two clickable URLs like this:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/ 
https://en.wiktionary.org/
```

Press space at the end of each line. Insert a newline by pressing **Control+Enter**. On a Mac, **⌥ + Enter**.